# How come it Is valid to use `DATE` data type in Character functions?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, concatenation

Edit 1: Based on comments of user hwd, I realized functions which are said to accept only any of the datatypes `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, or `NCLOB` are still accepting `DATE`.

For suppose `concat` , `substr`,`lower` said to accept only any of the datatypes `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, or `NCLOB`.But the following are still valid.

```
select concat('xyz',to_date('25-07-17')) from dual;
select substr(sysdate,1,5) from dual;
select lower(sysdate) from dual;
```

Before Edit 1:

Question : Is `SYSDATE` implicitly converted to `CLOB`data during `CONCAT`?

I am confused over following statments from document.

-[Parameters of `CONCAT` should be any of the datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, or NCLOB.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)

-[During concatenation operations, Oracle converts from noncharacter datatypes to `CHAR` or `NCHAR`.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51029).But I feel it some way contradicts [Implicit Type Conversion Matrix](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51029) as it shows `DATE` cannot be converted to `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`.

-[Most SQL character functions are enabled to accept CLOBs as parameters.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51029)

So I am wondering how is `concat('xyz',sysdate)`valid? what data type is sysdate converted to?

Comment: "as it shows `DATE` cannot be converted to `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`" -- The matrix appears to be saying the exact opposite to me. Have you tried using `SYSDATE` in a context where the only type it could possibly convert to is `CHAR`? If so, what happened?

Comment: I have not come across any function that accepts only `CHAR`. But most of functions which are said to accept only any of the datatypes `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, or `NCLOB` are still accepting `DATE`.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a function. One way to test an implicit conversion would be by inserting into a table where the column type is one of the character types. In that context, none of the other character types would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > what data type is sysdate converted to?

You can deduce the datatype by using the dump() function, which emits the data type of the input:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yy';

Session altered.

SQL> select dump(concat('xyz',to_date('25-07-17'))) from dual;

DUMP(CONCAT('XYZ',TO_DATE('25-07-17')))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=11: 120,121,122,50,53,45,48,55,45,49,55
```

Since concat is producing data type 1 VARCHAR2, the date value must be coerced to VARCHAR2.

The link's Table 2-10 clearly shows DATE can be coerced to CHAR, NCHAR, VARCHAR2, and NVARCHAR2. The 'X' values in the matrix means `X can be implicitly converted to Y`.

The conversion is made possible primarily by the session parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT. But you can list all of them with the `show parameter nls` sqlplus command (which should also work in sqldeveloper and sqlcl).

Comment: one doubt though, I guess `DUMP` give data type of output and not the input. If it was input there is more than one parameter but only one output of `Typ`.

Comment: You can easily change the expression to dump(to_date('25-07-17')). That's why dump is as useful as it is.

Comment: I was asking what happens when you want to find out for function which necessarily need more than one argument.

Comment: @sql_dummy I'm not entirely clear what you mean by your last comment. Can you elaborate or should you ask another question formally instead of in the comments?

Comment: Its just a small doubt. let func be a function that needs 2 arguments. Does DUMP(func(arg1,arg2)) give datatype of arg1 or arg2 or the dataype of the output of func.

Comment: It dumps the output of func(), which allows you to deduce the coercions if arg1 and arg2 are not the same data type. You can then express dump(arg1) and dump(arg2) to see their unadulterated data types. Then you should be able to go to the implicit type conversion matrix to see the X where would expect to see the X.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150240/discussion-between-sql-dummy-and-jeff6times7).